# TCP receiver device on localhost

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, localhost, econnrefused

This is my situation (on real device, NOT emulator): 
I have an **App_A** that streams some data via TCP to another software that may be an **App_B** on the same device. 
 
In the **App_A** user manual, it is said it is possible to stream data to another app (**App_B** in this case) on the same device simply changing the destination_IP to "localhost" and destination_port to "8888" through an option offered in **App_A**. 
So, the data flow is from *source* to *App_a* and finally to *App_B*.

In this scenario, I am developing the App_B as a TCP Client app that listens to any streamed TCP data on the device.

This is the code I wrote (found on the web):

MAINACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TcpClient mTcpClient;
  Context context;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      context = this;
      new ConnectTask().execute("");
  }


  public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

      @Override
      protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(values);
          //response received from server
          Toast.makeText(context, "Ricevo "+values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.e("test", "response " + values[0]);
          //process server response here....

      }
  }
}
```

TCP_CLIENT

```
public class TcpClient {

  public static final String SERVER_IP = "localhost";
  public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8888;

  private String mServerMessage;
  private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;

  private boolean mRun = false;
  private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
  private BufferedReader mBufferIn;


  public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
      mMessageListener = listener;
  }

  public void sendMessage(String message) {
      if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
          mBufferOut.println(message);
          mBufferOut.flush();
      }
  }

  public void stopClient() {

      mRun = false;

      if (mBufferOut != null) {
          mBufferOut.flush();
          mBufferOut.close();
      }

      mMessageListener = null;
      mBufferIn = null;
      mBufferOut = null;
      mServerMessage = null;
  }

  public void run() {

      mRun = true;

      try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT)) {

            //sends the message to the server
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            //receives the message which the server sends back
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {

                mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        }
        //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
        // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.


      } catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

      }

  }

  public interface OnMessageReceived {
      public void messageReceived(String message);
  }

 }
```

My problem is that every value I put as first argument in the Socket constructor (in TcpClient Class > run method > try with resources statement), it throws the following Exception: 
 `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8888): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

I tried to write all the next statements but I cannot solve this issue: 
     `try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", SERVER_PORT)) ....` 
     `try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", SERVER_PORT)) ....` 
     `try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT))  ....` 
     `try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), SERVER_PORT))  ....`

I read that localhost IP must be "10.0.2.2" only if I need to access to localhost on the emulator, and this is not my case. Anyway, I tried also this option on the device, but it does not work and a ConnectException with ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) is thrown.

I know my code is not optimized for this case, but currently I only care on having the TCP communication properly working and not about performance issues.
I would ask your help and I will be really grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Both the apps are running on the same real device, not on the emulator. I don't undestand what you mean since adb is a command line tool running on the PC

Comment: I am a bit confused. You wrote that `I am developing the App_B as a TCP Client app that listens...` TCP clients normally do not listen and the App_B does not listen. It creates a client socket. But the App_A is probably also client - `destination_IP to "localhost" and destination_port to "8888" through an option offered in App_A.` Which of application should be a TCP server?

Comment: I don't have for sure an answer to your question. The only thing I know about App_A is that it streams the data via TCP to another software, that in my case must be a second app (indeed App_B). Thus I thought to create App_B in way that it is able to listen all the TCP stream from App_A. If you have suggestions and any other explanations, please share with me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Here the specification as written in the user manual: "The Range Extender functionality allows to connect the sensor (source data) to our app running on Android mobile device (App_A), and to send the data via a TCP connection to a receiving PC running our Software
(default TCP port 8888).
By changing the receiving IP address to ”localhost” (from App_A settings menu), it is possible to send the data to another app (App_B) running on the same mobile device.
The protocol is currently only a one-way protocol from the mobile application to the receiver (App_B or PC)."

Comment: TCP connection establishment is an asymetric process. One party acts as a server and the other acts as a client. The description is a bit misleading from my point of view but I guess the App_A acts as a client. The App_B must act as a server - that means it should create an instance of `ServerSocket` instead of `Socket`.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. 
App_B acts as server and not as a client. I am sorry, I cannot imagine the solution was so simple. 
Thank you again.